# Calling a function with user defined datatypes in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I defined a data type in Haskell

```
data List a=Nil
 |Cons a (List a)
```

I wrote a function using this data type

```
listLength Nil=0
listLength (Cons x xs)=1+listLength(xs)
```

I tried to call that function giving arguments like this

```
listLength (Cons 2 [2,3])
```

But I got an error:

```
<interactive>:68:20: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `List Integer'
                  with actual type `[Integer]'
    * In the second argument of `Cons', namely `[2, 3]'
      In the first argument of `listLength', namely `(Cons 2 [2, 3])'
      In the expression: listLength (Cons 2 [2, 3])
```

How do  call this function?

Comment: Try `listLength (Cons 2 (Cons 2 Nil))`. The issue is that `[2,3]` has type `[Integer]`, but the `Cons` constructor requires a second argument of type `List Integer`, and due to Haskell's strong typing the two types are not the same!

Comment: It worked. Thank you

Comment: To ease testing you can define and use some auxiliary conversion function like `fromList = foldr Cons Nil` and then write `listLength (fromList [1,7,2,5]))`. In this way you can convert standard lists to your lists before testing, and avoid to type all the `Cons`es.

Comment: @Nishara Kavindi Do you want me to turn my comment into a proper answer so this question can be marked as 'answered'?

Comment: @bradrn Okey.You can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment above:

> Try using `listLength (Cons 2 (Cons 2 Nil))`. The issue is that `[2,3]` has type `[Integer]`, but the `Cons` constructor requires a second argument of type `List Integer`, and due to Haskell's strong typing the two types are not the same!